# How to compare the dates and gets the day count using c# in LINQ

Tags: linq

i want to compare the date given with the current date and i want to get the number of days by using linq

thanks,
Vara Prasad.M

Comment: Why LINQ? How are you using it in LINQ?

Comment: Could you do something like `dtCurrent.Subtract(dtGiven).Days`? What is the reason you are trying to use LINQ?

Comment: in a grid i want to check the given date with the dates under the grid how it can be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the need to use Linq for this.

```
DateTime givenDate; // given by earlier code
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan timeSpan = givenDate.Subtract(currentDate);

int timeSpanInDays = timeSpan.Days;
```

Comment: in a grid i want to check the given date with the current date so that why i want to use the linq concept here. under linq how it can be done?

Comment: @Vara can you add a piece of your code to the question so I can see where to add my code? Are you DataBinding a collection to a `GridView`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm making the assumption that you are looping through something which contains the date. I've used a `DataTable` and `DataRow`.
I don't know your case exactly, so adjust this as needed for what you are doing.

I created this foreach loop

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in new System.Data.DataTable().Rows)
{
    DateTime givenDate = DateTime.Parse(row[0].ToString());
    TimeSpan timeSpan = givenDate.Subtract(currentDate);

    if (timeSpan.Days > 10)
    {
        Foo(timeSpan.Days);
    }

}
```

Using the awesome power of [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), it has been transformed into

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
foreach (TimeSpan timeSpan in
    new System.Data.DataTable().Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(row => DateTime.Parse(row[0].ToString()))
    .Select(givenDate => givenDate.Subtract(currentDate))
    .Where(timeSpan => timeSpan.Days > 10))
{
    Foo(timeSpan.Days);
}
```

Obviously this may need to be tweaked based your needs. I wasn't sure what you needed the days for, so I included an `if` on the days. Were you to just pass the value somewhere, or use the value, the LINQ query would drop the `.Where(...)`.

I hope this helps. I'm not clear on what you need LINQ for... But there's some LINQ. :)

(I have no association with JetBrains or Resharper other than loving the tool.)